# Morphing with CoreAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, core-animation, morphing

I am creating an Navigation Button. When user presses it, the image  of the button should change, reflecting it's state (e.g. menu opened / closed). I decided to do a morphing-liek animation for this. Is it possible to implement with CoreAnimation? What animation type do I need to use?
I attached the picture to clearly illustrate what I want. Also, you might see these animations in "Pimp My Ride" show.
[image: Morphing sample]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [animationImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimageview_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889-CH3-SW2) property of UIImageView for this, like this:

```
myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageViewbounds];

//Add images which will be used for the animation using an array. These should exist in your project and bundle already.
myImageView.animationImages =  @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]];

//Set the duration of the entire animation
myImageView.animationDuration = 0.5;

//Set the repeat count. If you don't set that value, by default will be a loop (infinite)
myImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

//Start the animation
[myImageView startAnimating];
```

To ensure smooth morphing like transition you may check out [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) which has many great blur filters. Ideally you should be able to wrap a blur animation between two image animations to achieve what you want.

Comment: But I use UIButton? Does it the same as you mentioned?

Comment: This is for imageview. If you want touch processing in it add gestureRecognizer to it and set userInteractionEnabled to YES.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with UIButton or its the only way to implement it?

Comment: Actually - yes: I can use property of UIButton named "imageView" and  implement this solution, but this is not morphing. The files need to be pre-processed in some software, e.g. after effects, so its kinda weird. Still looking for "pure morph" solution.

Comment: Have you checked out GPUImage on github? It has lot many image filters and I believe if you could derive your UIButton to use the GPUImage you will get desired effect.

Comment: Nope, but GPUImage seems to be a nice solution for this particular case and for rendering all the blurs etc in app.

Comment: I saw your comment, but blur has nothing to do with morphing.